# Firebase Storage Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

When I try to upload an image to the storage I get this error :

[image: Error]

I have already tried changing the dependencies and the versions but nothing has changed. I have also tried several times to modify my code by removing or modifying a part but always the same error coming back.

Here is the code which manages the selection of the photo and sends it to the sockage. I also have the line firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(); at the top of my code but this one is 400 lines long so I won't post the whole code.

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {          // Crop selected photo
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            resultUri = result.getUri();
            profileImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}

private void addPictureFirebase() {                                                             // Add photo to storage
    storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();
    myReference = storageReference.child(userUid);

    storageReference.getName().equals(myReference.getName());

    if (resultUri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sélectionner d'abord une photo"+resultUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        storageReference.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Photo envoyée avec succès !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        storageReference.putFile(resultUri).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Erreur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: check if the userId you re passing to your reference is null or not first

Comment: @takieddine check the path he used it's wrong path means there is no reference and file details

Comment: I have already tested and this one is not null on output. The condition that checks if the value is null does not come out. This is the addOnFailureListener that pops up when I click on the send button in the storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
storageReference.putFile(resultUri).addSuccessListener()
```

With this

```
myReference.putFile(resultUri).addSuccessListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code :

```
storageReference.putFile(resultUri)
```

You have used blank path for the reference. Just the following code with this :

```
myReference = storageReference.child(userUid+".png");
```

Comment: I modified the line as said above but it didn't change anything. I have to modify storageReference.putFile(resultUri) ?

Comment: @JorisRicard yes you have to do it.

Comment: I must put a path ? Because currently there is no path and this is the reason why the images do not send, right ?